# Pattern match on data types

Tags: haskell

I have been struggling with this problem so far and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. This is my template so far:

```
data Expense = MkExpense Double String deriving (Eq,Ord)

mkExpense :: String -> Double -> Expense
mkExpense name amount = MkExpense amount name

instance Show Expense where
  show (MkExpense amount name) = name ++ ": " ++ show amount

data Delta = MkDelta Expense deriving (Eq,Ord)

instance Show Delta where
  show (MkDelta (MkExpense amount name)) = name ++ ": " ++ show amount
```

Right now I would like to sum over all the amounts of a list of the form (so in this case I would like to get `240`):

```
[mkExpense "Alex" 40, mkExpense "Gert-Jan" 200]
```

which returns:

```
[Alex: 40.0,Gert-Jan: 200.0]
```

I know of the existence of `foldr` but I'm not sure how to pattern match properly against the "amounts" here. Normally I would use `map` to re-map to a single value list so I can use `foldr` freely, but it's not possible here because of my definition of the show-instance I presume.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how the Show instance prevents anything. Have you tried using `map` and `foldr` (or just `sum`)?

Comment: @Noughtmare How would you use map here? Because the following doesnt work: ```map(\(name: amount) -> amount) list``` or ```map(\(mkExpense name amount) -> amount) list``` doesn't work either.

Comment: ```map(\(MkExpense amount name) -> amount) [MkExpense 40 "Alex", MkExpense 200 "Gert-Jan"]``` works, but using mkExpense bugs out.

Comment: The first is just invented syntax, the second tries to use a function to pattern match, you can only pattern match using constructors like `MkExpense` you do the very same thing in your show instances so I'm a little stumped why you don't just use that. Aside: having opposite argument order on `mkExpense` and `MkExpense` seems unnecessarily confusing to me.

Comment: @cafce25 Hmm makes sense, I was also confused so I could have sworn I pattern matched on constructors a bunch of time. As for the mkExpense definition it's part of exercise. So is there no way to pattern match on functions? Or maybe a way to convert the function to the constructor immediately or something of the like?

Comment: You can define custom [Pattern Synonyms](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/pattern-synonyms)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `map`; the function supplied to `foldr` can pattern-match directly.

```
> foldr (\(MkExpense v _) t -> v + t) 0 [mkExpense "Alex" 40, mkExpense "Gert-Jan" 200]
240.0
```

The same technique can be used for composing `sum` and `map`:

```
> sum $ map (\(MkExpense v _) -> v) [mkExpense "Alex" 40, mkExpense "Gert-Jan" 200]
240.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`map (\(MkExpense amount name) -> amount) [mkExpense "Alex" 40, mkExpense "Gert-Jan" 200]`
does the trick, having "two constructors" where one flips the arguments caused the confusion as to why my map wasn't working.